# Make animation toggle on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hello i have the following...

```
 <span id="second" class="content1" style="width:0px; display:inline-block; overflow:hidden; float: left; white-space:nowrap;">
                    <p style="color:blue; background-color: #b5bdc8;">Camera Reviews</p>
                  </span>
                  <a href="#" class="slide1" style="float: left;"><li class="laptop"></li></a>
```

and the script is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
          $('.slide1').click(function () {
          $('#second').animate({
               width: '120px',
           }, 1000);
       });
 });
```

The problem is that i want the list to be displayed BLOCK... and work as it is PLUS i want the animation to toggle when i click on the list hide/show

Working code here: http://jsfiddle.net/gVjFs/81/

Comment: Uh, well first try to separate CSS from HTML.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your intended behavior? I'm not quite following.

Comment: OK i have separeted the html ffrom html here: http://jsfiddle.net/gVjFs/81/. Now i want the list display BLOCK and the animation to toggle on click show hide (for each and every list item)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14755580/1250044

Comment: `li` inside `a` ? `p` inside `span` ? really? And `float: left` turns the computed style to `display: block`. It makes no sense to use a `display: whatever` when using `float`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to ignore the dodgy markup (`<li>` inside `<span>` among other things). You can use [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) here:

```
$('.slide1').toggle(function () {
    $('#second').stop().animate({
        width: '120px',
    }, 1000);
}, function(){
    $('#second').stop().animate({
        width: '0',
    }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your JSFiddle, you show that you are setting the CSS to `block` for `ul li`. But this won't work because you do not have any `ul` tags in your HTML. It also appears that you are using `li` tags incorrectly. An `li` tag is like a `td` tag: it does not make sense outside of its parent tag. For `li`'s that would be an `ol` or a `ul` tag. If you want a little circle to click on, use an image of a little circle. Also, wrap your `span` / `a` section in a `div`. That will give you blocked display for free.

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of click() and [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)
Something like this:

```
$("#click").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('whatever');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.slide1, .slide2, .slide3, .slide4, .slide5').click(function () {
        var elem = $('.' + $(this).attr('class').replace('slide','content')),
            width = elem.width();
        elem.animate({
            width: width === 0 ? '120px' : 0,
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

**[demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/NeHS7/)**

I advise you to set a `slide` class to all your `.slide1, .slide2, .slide3`-elements.